# how to set end date when select the start date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

i want to set end date  depend on the balance and start date when the user select the start date,

for example if the start date is `2021-09-01` the balance is `11` so direct the end date will be `2021-09-12`

i'm using DatePicer from `ant Design`  ,

this is my code

````
useEffect(() => {
    if (
      (selectedLeaveId && selectedLeaveId === LeavesId.annualLeaveId)
    ) {
      const start = startDate;
// this will change the start date too , i dont want that 
      const directEndDate = start?.add(remainingBalance, 'days');
      setEndDate(directEndDate);
    }
  }, [selectedLeaveId, startDate, remainingBalance]);```
````

Answer (score 0):

Strongly recommend using moment.js
https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/01-add/

You can pass date as below

```
let start = moment(startDate)
let end = start.add(DIFFERENCE, 'days');
```

Comment: startDate and endDate is moment type , so if i do this it will change also the startDate

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is because you are modifying the `start` date object and assigning it to `end`. I'm not up-to-date on the specifics of moment js but I'd imagine you can do something like:

```
let end = moment(start).add(DIFFERENCE, 'days');
```

That way you'll create a new date object for `end` and add to that one, rather than modifying `start`.

---

As a side note, if you aren't going to change what's in the `start` or `end` variables you'd be better off writing `const start ...` rather than `let start ...` (it will prevent certain bugs from creeping in). This won't prevent you from changing the objects through their methods, it just stops you from accidentally reassigning them.